# How to check if entire html page is loaded based on <html> function by Web Driver C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, selenium-webdriver

I want to use Selenium WebDrier with C# to check content of page.

The problem is that my page is reloading partly, not entire page every time i do something. When I click, page is reloading and after that I want to click next step of my TC, so functions WaitForPageToLoad, waitForElementVisible is not working (don't know why) or something are not working. They Give me errors like "Unable to find element....". I don't want to use functions like Thread.sleep(1000000) I want to check if page is loaded and after that run my actions.

So I figured out that there is a .js function in my HTML that runs every time I commit something (I think so).

The script looks like that :

```
function(a) {   
    if (a === !0 && !--e.readyWait || a !== !0 && !e.isReady) {
        if (!c.body) 
            return setTimeout(e.ready, 1);
        e.isReady = !0;
        if (a !== !0 && --e.readyWait > 0)
            return;
        A.fireWith(c, [e]), e.fn.trigger && e(c).trigger("ready").off("ready")   
    } 
}

function onload(event) {
    onload()
}
```

after that there is my  and  sections.

The question is: How to check if this function is running and when it ends to make my webDriver scripts run ??

Comment: @LenapCapo The `document.ready` function only executes once when the page initially loads, unless you include it with the loading HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no one-size-fits-all solution to this problem.

The long answer is that you have to know how the page behaves in detail. If you click a button, what else on the page changes? I would think of the page as different zones. Each zone is a part of the page that is dynamic and might potentially change on a page action. Once you establish these different zones, find an element that exists in each zone and wait for that element when that zone gets updated.

A zone might be a calendar control or a list or a table and so on. Pick an element from the calendar control that always exists and wait for it to be visible when you trigger an action that refreshes the calendar. Do this for each zone and you should be good. Using the page object model would help significantly in implementing, maintaining, and using this.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for `document.readyState`. It has 3 possible values

1. **loading**: The document is still loading / being parsed
2. **interactive**: It has finished loading / parsing, but resources like images, stylesheets and frames are still loading
3. **complete**:  Everything is loaded.

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't account for Ajax calls or any other dynamic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this : 
Where InputArgs are [xpath_to_find, timeput]

private void waitForXpathToBeVisibleWithTimeout(String[] inputArgs)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(inputArgs[1]); i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(inputArgs[0]));
                    break;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(inputArgs[0]));


  }
```

And it works nice !